# Modify value of attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-data

How to modify the value of data-tooltip? I would like to do that with one line of code.

Here is the element:

```
<li class="ui-btn-icon-left " data-icon="cf">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-cf">
    <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="NeverGiveUp">Samaras</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Here are two of my attempts:

```
$($(li).find('a').find('span').attr('data-tooltip')).val('foo');
$($(li).find('a').find('span').attr('data-tooltip')).text('foo');
```

which had no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the straight forward answer is `.attr('data-tooltip', 'new value');`. However, it is also possible, and more recommended (see hjpotter92's comment), to use `.data('tooltip', 'new value');`

Comment: Two methods suggested, very nice! And the question is: which one should I use? Are they equivalent? What what would you suggest?

Comment: Thank @hjpotter92. JCOC611, you should update your answer with the gist of the link that jhpotter92 kindly provided, in order to make clear why we should prefer the one method over the other. That way your answer will be far better!

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because `.attr()` approach was the one that really worked in my actual application.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest notation would be:

```
$('li a span').data('tooltip', 'foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do the following:

```
$('li a').find('span').data('tooltip', 'foo');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, +1 for the complete answer.

Comment: @gsamaras Ah! It would be `,`. Typing on a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.data()`:

```
$($(li).find('a').find('span').data('tooltip', 'foo'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify that to:

```
$("li a span").data("tooltip", "foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

For HTML 5 data-attributes, you can use [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$($(li).find('a').find('span').data('tooltip', 'foo'));
```

Comment: Thank you, however, such kind of an answer is already provided. Next time, you will have to be faster! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple with data-attribute

```
$('.tooltip[data-tooltip]').data('tooltip', 'foo');
```